# C++ boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator problem

Tags: c++, boost-iterators

I have this class:

```
template <class S, class P, class A>
class Task
{
  private:

    timeval start;
    boost::ptr_vector<S> states;
    boost::ptr_vector<P> policies;

  public:

    P findPolicy(S *state);
    S findState(S *state);

};
```

When I try to define findPolicy or findState using an iterator:

```
template <class S, class P, class A>
S Task<S,P,A>::findState(S *state)
{
  boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator it;
  for ( it = policies.begin(); it < policies.end(); ++it)
  {
    // blah 
  }
}
```

Defined after the class, compiler says:

```
error: expected ';' before it;
```

Even trying to define the function in the class declaration gives me the same error.
I'm puzzled since this is how I've been using boost::ptr_vector iterators so far.
The only thing that seems to work is good old fashioned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < policies.size(); i++)
  {
    if (policies[i].getState() == state)
    {
     return policies[i];
    }
  }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: It's always a good idea, when posting an error, to point out the line that the error appears on.

Comment: Don't use "it < policies.end()". Correct is "it != policies.end()"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator it;
```

This needs to use the C++ keyword `typename`:

```
typename boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator it;
```

Otherwise, C++ doesn't know what `ptr_vector<S>::iterator` is supposed to be. This is because the definition of `ptr_vector<S>` depends on the template parameter `S`, and the value of `S` is not known at the time of the template's definition. But the compiler needs to be able to make sense of the line `ptr_vector<S>::iterator` without knowing what `S` is exactly.

So compilers assume that dependent names are variables (so a static member of `ptr_vector<S>`); you need to use `typename` in order to tell the compiler that the dependent name is a type and not a variable.

Comment: @Alex: The problem is that `boost::ptr_vector<S>` is dependent on template parameter `S` and so the compiler has no way of knowing whether it is a type or a value. When such an ambiguity arises, it assumes it is value, which then leads to compilation errors. Qualifying the declaration with the `typename` keyword tells the compiler to treat it as a dependent type.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add typename - I think you need:

```
typename boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator it;
```

Whenever with templates you see some error like:

```
error: expected ';' before it;
```

It is because the type in front of `it` is not being seen by the compiler as a type and so one needs to add a `typename`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't explain the error message IMO, but in the code you posted you assign a `boost::ptr_vector<S>::iterator` variable with a `boost::ptr_vector<P>::iterator` value.

Comment: @Alex - In `findState` you use a `vector<S>::iterator` when `policies` is a `vector<P>`. Of course this depends on the actual S and P, so sometimes it might be ok.